# Problem with RIA Services and POCO classes, associated child collection not being sent

Tags: silverlight-4.0, poco, wcf-ria-services, dto

Here's my setup: I have some "data", which is actually a graph of objects (DTOs representing SSAS objects) that I want serialized and sent via RIA Services for consumption by a silverlight app. Here's a simple example of that:

```
public class Database
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set;}

   public string Name { get; set;}

   [Include]
   [Association("DatabaseCue", "ID", "DatabaseID"]
   public IEnumerable<Cube> Cubes { get; set;}
}
public class Cube
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set;}

   public int DatabaseID { get; set;}

   public string Name { get; set;}

   // other Cube properties
}
```

And I have a `DomainService`:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class AmoService : DomainService
{
   public IQueryable<Database> GetDatabases()
   {
       return myAmoAdapter.GetDatabases();
   }
}
```

`myAmoAdapter.GetDatabases()` retrieves the Database collection, filling also its child Cubes collection just fine, however, in the client side, the cubes collection is empty! I can't figure out how to make this work! (or maybe it just won't?!)

Anybody know why this isn't working and how to fix it? I would be grateful.

Comment: Do all the cubes have the same ID value (0)? I mean are you sending the objects by just generating them without an id and not really persisting them to the db (when the key would actually get generated)?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that appears different from how I do this is public IEnumerable Cubes { get; set;}.  I would usually do that as:

```
public List<Cube> Cubes { get; set;}
```

Also, you need a Composition tag as follows:

```
[Include]
[Composition]
[Association("DatabaseCue", "ID", "DatabaseID"]
public IEnumerable<Cube> Cubes { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check on the client side if it has a an `EntitySet` for `Cube`?

If that is not available, then you also need to tell RIA Services that `Cube` is a class that should be generated on the client. You can do this by defining a dummy method like this on the server side:

```
public IQueryable<Cube> GetCubesDummy()
{
   return new List<Cube>().AsQueryable();
}
```

If the `EntitySet` exists, you should also check if the Foreign-Keys are ok. Just because the collection is populated on the server, it doesn't mean that the `DatabaseID` in the `Cube` elements is correct.

Comment: The entity types on the client side for all my classes are generated just fine. I don't know what do you mean exactly by the "EntitySet" on the client. And, for your second note, yeah, the foreign keys are OK. :)

Comment: @AbdouMoumen With `EntitySet` I mean the `DomainContext.Cubes` property, which uses `DomainContext.GetEntitySet<Cube>()`. Could you check if there are any objects in `DomainContext.Cubes` after calling the method? If so, then the `DatabaseID` is wrong and the generated filter does not find the right elements.

Comment: The property (Cubes) has been generated, but no objects in there :(

Comment: @AbdouMoumen In that case I think that the child collections are not properly filled on the server side. Your `Include` and `Association` attributes look ok. Therefore, if no objects are sent over the wire, there seem to be none.

Comment: that's the weird part. I checked the collections on the server side (as I mentioned in the question) and they're filled just fine! I rechecked the foregn keys and they're all well too!

Comment: @AbdouMoumen If you use a RIA method to load `Cubes` only, do you get results in `DomainContext.Cubes`? Another possible issue that I can think of is that you may have some code that does a `DomainContext.Cubes.Clear()` after handling the LoadOperation for `GetDatabasesAsync()`. In order to narrow down the possible problems, you can also create an EventHandler that listens on `DomainContext.Cubes.EntityAdded`. (Sorry, not sure if that works.)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the `IsForeignKey` property of the `Association` attribute on the `Database` object

```
[Include]
[Association("DatabaseCue", "ID", "DatabaseID", IsForeignKey = false]
public IEnumerable<Cube> Cubes { get; set;}
```

Comment: this hasn't worked either :( I'm starting to think the problem is somewhere else, but I just can't see where!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want try is to initialize the Cubes collection on Database in the constructor.

```
public class Database
{
  public Database
  {
    Cubes = new List<Cube>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set;}

  public string Name { get; set;}

  [Include]
  [Association("DatabaseCue", "ID", "DatabaseID"]
  public IEnumerable<Cube> Cubes { get; set;}
}
```

RIA Services can sometimes exhibit some strange behavior if Associated Entity collections are not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that it would work if I added the child to the parent's collection and also specifically set the parent id.

So

```
    Database db = ...

    db.Cubes.Add(new Cube(){ID=1, DatabaseID=db.ID, Name = "Cube1" });
```

if I didn't have the DatabaseID=db.ID they would be set to zero and nothing would be returned by RIA Services.  Bug?